# Perl SOAP::Lite Adding CDATA

Tags: perl, cdata, soaplite

I am calling a web service using [SOAP::Lite](https://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP::Lite) module as follows:

```
my $som = $soap->call('ns:xxx' =>
           (
            SOAP::Data->name('ns:data' =>
            \SOAP::Data->value(
               SOAP::Data->name('username')->type('')->value($username),
             )
          )
      )
  );
```

It did not work. So I called web service using SOAPUI tool to see xml structure.

Then I run my code at debug mode (use SOAP::Lite 'debug'), see created xml and compared with the xml of SOAPUI tool. The only difference is that SOAPUI xml contains CDATA tag as follow:

```
<![CDATA[
   xml
]]>
```

I searched and saw that CDATA is used to prevent error caused by special characters

How can I add this tag using Perl code?

Answer (score 0):

Use XML::Generator to encode the CDATA section. Then put it in the relevant soap structure.

Comment: I created CDATA but unfortunately SOAP::Data->value() replaces  character '<' with '&lt;' and character '>' with '&gt;'

Comment: The type should be: SOAP::Data->type('xml' => $xml_content)